# Moving objects with Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm making an application with Microsoft Kinect on Visual Studio 15 (WPF) and I need to take objects with both hands and move in a given period of time. does anybody know how to start? Im a newbie with kinect.
It would be appreciated. thanks you all

Answer (score 1):

For the quick start just use these [quick start series](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart)
it contains all what you need to get a start. But what you are trying to do here is not very clear. Obviously you can get your hand positions very easily.